# Uncaught TypeError: createTransitionManager2.default

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am setting up a React app with Typescript, and I keep on getting a type error with BrowserHistory

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _createTransitionManager2.default) is not a function
>       at createBrowserHistory

index.ts:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import { App } from "./components";

const ROOT = document.querySelector("#app");

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    ROOT
);
```

App.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import { Home } from "../containers/Home";

export const App = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
);
```

Home.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

export const Home = () => <div>Home</div>;
```

package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.4.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jest": "^23.1.1",
        "@types/react": "^16.4.1",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.7",
        "parcel-bundler": "^1.9.2",
        "tslint": "^5.7.0",
        "typescript": "^2.9.2"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `"@types/history": "^4.6.2",` and worked!